# Angularjs Login Authentication: Prevent user navigate to other page except login page and registration page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, basic-authentication

I am developing a web application by using AngularJS framework for my frontend. For my login page, I have to prevent user browse to other page except login page and registration. But the code that what I did now, prevent user navigate to registration page also. The following is my code. How can I solve this problem in order that enable user to browse to login page and registration page only if the user without login.

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, nextParams, fromState) {

    if ('data' in next && 'authorizedRoles' in next.data) {
      var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
      if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
      }
    }

    if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
      if (next.name !== 'login') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Tips: do not name  `next` as parameter as they are keyword in node  and might conflicts

Comment: @pro.mean Must have next as parameter. If not application is not worked.

Comment: i mean to say change the parameter name only. see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this by adding one boolean parameter in data property of `.state`, let say `requiresAuth` and check that also in **.run** block;

below are pseudo code for that

in **.config** block

```
 $stateProvider
  .state("register", {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller:'UserController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
            requiresAuth: false,
            pageTitle: 'Register'                
        }
 })
 .state("dashboard", {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller:'OtherController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
            authorizedRoles: ['WHATEVER_ROLE']
        }
});
```

and in **.run** block

```
var stateChangeStart = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        // if user trying to access register/forgot page after login than redirect to dashboard
        if (!toState.data.requiresAuth) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
        }
        // user is not authenticated and trying to access page which is not permissible than send back to dashboard
        if (angular.isDefined(toState.data.authorizedRoles)) {
            var roles = toState.data.authorizedRoles;
            AuthService.isAuthorized(roles).catch(function() { // NOTE: here we are only handling with .catch block
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
            });
        }
    }
    // user is not authenticated than redirect to login
    else if (toState.data.requiresAuth) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
    }
});

 var notAuthenticated = $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function() {
        $log.warn('not authenticated');
        $state.go('login', null, {});
        return;
    });

    var notAuthorized = $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized, function() {
        $log.warn('not authorized');
        $state.go('dashboard');
        return;
    });

    // DO NOT forget to destroy 
    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', notAuthenticated);
    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', notAuthorized);
    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', stateChangeStart);
```

Comment: I said this is pseudo code, you have to modify according to your need